# Best way to cache pictures in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, hive, firebase-storage

I have created an app using dart/Flutter where users are able to store photos. These photos are stored in FireStorage but every time the app opens it takes a while until all photos are loaded due to the large resolution of the pics. So, I was thinking if its better for every user to store locally the pictures and every time he/she opens the app to download only the new ones and not every photo.

In order to do this, I thought using [HiveDB](https://docs.hivedb.dev) but I wanted to know first if there is any better solution than hivedb or any common practice for caching data. Do you think the approach of caching such a vast amount of pictures is a bad idea in general (i.e. takes too much space on users smartphone). Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this package [Cached network image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) => 
                CircularProgressIndicator(value: downloadProgress.progress),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Check flutter [cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/cached-images) demonstrates image catching with [`cache_network_image`](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) plugin